# Comparing pointers (char array) in C/C++

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Having some issues comparing char arrays thru pointers. I am working without both the string library and iostream, would like to keep it that way.

```
char *GetCurrentPath()
{
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
if (!GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH)) {
    printf("GetModuleFileNameA failed, error: %d\n", GetLastError());
}
return (buffer);


}
char *GetInstallPath()
{
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
if (!SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL, buffer, CSIDL_APPDATA, FALSE)) {
    printf("SHGetSpecialFolderPathA failed, error: %d\n", GetLastError());
}
strcat(buffer, "\\service.exe");

    return (buffer);
}



char *InstallPath = GetInstallPath();
char *CurrentPath = GetCurrentPath();

if (InstallPath == CurrentPath)......
```

The if statement causes an instant crash, same goes for strcomp.

Suggestions?

Comment: You cannot safely return pointers to local variables.

Comment: Hint: Those two *pointers* will never be the same ... You are using library `string` syntax for plain `char *` strings.

Comment: Can you clarify what language you are using - **either C or C++**? Your title and tags mention both, which is not possible (which is probably why the tag  "C++" got edited out). However, the statement "without the string library and iostream" *strongly* suggests C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currently doing is undefined behavior. The buffers that you are using in the two functions are defined locally to those functions and go out of scope the moment the functions end, giving you pointers to random stack addresses.

You need to either allocate the buffers in the functions:

Replace : `char buffer[MAX_PATH];`

With: `char *buffer = new char[MAX_PATH]`

Or pass allocated buffers from your main to the functions:

```
char *InstallPath = new char[MAX_PATH];
GetInstallPath(InstallPath);
```

And change your get path functions:

```
char *GetInstallPath(char *buffer)
```

In both cases, you will have to delete your pointers before ending your program to free up the memory.

On top of that, when you try to compare the two variables, they will compare pointer addresses rather than string contents. You will need to use `strcmp()` or something in that family of functions.

Comment: So the pointer does not point to the return value of the functions?

Comment: @MelvinLangvik The return value of the function is invalid as it contains an address to a local variable that is no longer in scope.

Comment: Ahh, so i'm pointing to a function which return value is out of the scope, due to the return value it self being a pointer, therefor pointing to something inside the local scope of the function.

Comment: @MelvinLangvik Not exactly, but close. The return value of the function is a pointer, so you are taking that value and storing it in your pointer variables, not pointing to a function. The value of that pointer is simply invalid, as it refers to a memory location that has been freed upon function exit.

Comment: So if i change the function/return value to a normal char array, i can make a pointer to that inside the scope of main() and use that to satisfy all my WinApi calls?

Comment: @MelvinLangvik I added some clarification. Note that I am using C++ in my examples.

Comment: What is so weird is that before and after implementing your solution, i get the same result before the if statement, i print out the "Installpath" using printf and i get the char array i'm looking for, but neither if or strcmp manages to compare correctly... guess i'm further then before, thankyou.

Comment: @MelvinLangvik care to show what your `strcmp` call looks like?

Comment: No need, fixed. The rest of the code killed the impact of the strcmp, its fixed and working :)

Answer (score 0):

Your functions return an array (char *) declared locally inside them. Your pointers have undefined values outside the functions. You can't do that.

You may allocate them dynamically:

```
 char *buffer = malloc(MAX_PATH*sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both buffers are allocated on stack, they are freed after the function execution ends. So, the pointers function returns becomes invalid.

To fix that, you have to allocate buffer[] on heap, using char * buffer = new char[MAX_PATH];

But after you will have to free the memory manually.